# textures are always on the bottom of my plane

Tags: texturing, normals

i'm trying to add a texture to a plane but when i do the texture is always projected on the bottom of the plan (even if i flip the plane). i tried flipping the normals but that didn't help.

[image: node setup]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand, could you please pack your images and share your file?

Comment: Have you tried plugging the UV or Object output from the Texture Coordinate node into the Mapping node?

Comment: You should also plug the output from the mapping node into the Vector input of all the image nodes, not just the main colour one.

Comment: Hey moonboots! how would i go about packing my images and sharing it? do you have link, sry i'm new to this.. And yes i've ried using the UV or Object outputs but that doesn't change anything

Comment: In Blender, File > External Data > Pack Resources and save the file. Then go to https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions.

Comment: You should change your NORMAL texture and DISPLACEMENT texture color space to NON COLOR instead of linear and connect your DIsplacement to the Height instead of the normal socket

Comment: Thx, that did the trick!!